# Javascript - custom url depending on selected option

Tags: javascript, url, select, parameters

```
<form name="myform" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-4 desc">Naziv marke: </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control" id="brandovi">
                    <option value="AllBrands" selected>Sve marke</option>
                    <option value="Dunlop">Dunlop</option>  
                    <option value="Fulda">Fulda</option>    
                    <option value="Goodyear">Goodyear</option>  
                    <option value="Sava">Sava</option>          
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="season" value="Summer"> <img width="20" src="img/ikone/summer.png" />
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="season" value="AllSeason"> <img width="20" src="img/ikone/allSeason.png" />
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="season" value="Winter"> <img width="20" src="img/ikone/winter.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-4 desc">Tip vozila:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="AllTypes"> Sve vrste </option>
                    <option value="fourxfour"> 4x4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Traži"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have this in HTML, so I need javascript code that will output custom URL depending on selected values

Url example

```
http://link.com/?brandovi=sava&sezona=zima&vrstaVozila=4x4
```

I tried several JS codes but I could not make it.
Please help.

Comment: Please show us some code you've tried... but basically if you use `GET` instead of `POST`, adapt your html with proper names and change your `action` to "http://link.com" , it would do the trick...

Comment: I tried just ones i found on internet, this is my first time I'm using javascript, so I don't know that much.

Comment: So I guess it's time to try and come here showing some code when you've tried... that's how you learn :-)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function brand(obj){
        var brand = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
        if (brand.value != "nothing"){
                window.location = document.URL +  '/?brandovi=' + brand.value;
        }
    }
</script>

I customized this, but it works on change selected and I want to change on button click. And this is just for one select option, I want to make it for three.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem :D

Here is the solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitUrl(form){
    var brandovi = document.getElementById("brandovi");
    var brand = brandovi.options[brandovi.selectedIndex].value;
    var vrsteVozila = document.getElementById("vrsteVozila");
    var vrsta = vrsteVozila.options[vrsteVozila.selectedIndex].value;

    var radios = document.getElementsByName('season');

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
    var sezona = radios[i].value;
}
    else{
        var sezona = '';
    }
}  
    window.location = 'http://localhost/wordpress/' +  '?brandovi=' + brand + '&sezona=' + sezona + '&vrstaVozila=' + vrsta;
}
```